# Releasing a Git project from a specific history and upward

Tags: git

I have a Git repository I want to make open source. It has hundreds of commits.

I want to release it to the public with the history starting at a particular commit and upwards. All downwards commits should be eliminated.

To explain better

GitRepo

- commit 5
- commit 4
- commit 3
- commit 2
- commit 1

I want the repo history to start from 3, with 2 downward eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested as duplicate by @jonrsharpe is accurate.

If you only have a handful of commits to "eliminate" from the beginning of your history, an alternative way is to use `git rebase --root -i`, and mark all the first commits to be squashed together :

```
pick aecf11 commit 1
squash aecf22 commit 2   # edit this line to 'squash'
squash aecf33 commit 3   # and this line too
pick aecf44 commit 4
pick aecf55 commit 5
```

The resulting history will start with one single commit, with the same content as `commit 3`.